# How to exclude an Android App from Battery Optimization using code

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to Android, now I am working on a Project which is based on GPS. I got source code from internet(traccar). my requirement is like the app should update location on each 1Km or each 1hr. but the problem is the app not working in background after some time(10 - 20 mins). Is there any solution for this ?

> what should I do(in code) to exclude this app from battery optimisation when the app is launching ? is it possible ?

Comment: If you want to get location in background then you need to use `Service` with get accurate location using `FusedLocationProviderAPI`. If your GPS and service will be continued then battery will be used. But for your optimization you can get location using `High` or `Low` accuracy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're having 2 different problems:

1) If you want to keep your app in background you should use a foreground Service. That way your app won't be considered to be in background by the system and the chances of its process being killed are reduced drastically. The downside is that as long as your Service is in foreground you need to show a permanent notification.

2) You cannot exclude your app from battery optimization yourself, but you can prompt the user the settings to whitelist your app. In order to do that you can refer to the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS), you'll need to add the `Manifest.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` permission to the manifest and then launch an intent with action [ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS). The user will then be able to whitelist your app, only she/he can do that because otherwise every app would whitelist itself and the purpose of the battery optimization would be defied.

Comment: Hi Lelloman, Thank you for the details answer. I have a question here, how WhatsApp, LinkedIn, telegram, and Messagener are excluded by default without showing a popup to the user.

Comment: Hey @MuhammadMaqsood I honestly don't know for sure. The only thing I know is that phone vendors do grant special treatment to such big companies, I wouldn't be surprised if those apps were whitelisted by default, have you checked the default OS settings?

Comment: 1st solution doesn't work on Chinese devices, the service still gets cutoff from internet etc.

Answer (score 6):

Add this permission in your manifest file Manifest.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS

Request Permission at runtime inside onCreate method of your activity...

```java
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
String packageName = "org.traccar.client";

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    Intent i = new Intent();

    if (!powerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
        i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
        i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

This is the image of the code in debug mode:
[image]

This will be the view in app:
[image]

but the application not working as it is in No Restriction mode (background activity).
I want the application to work as No Restriction mode.

Comment: I tried your solution by placing the above code in the onCreate method on the launcher activity but it did not work. It worked only when I moved the code into onStart. To whom it may concern

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission in your manifest file
Manifest.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS

Request Permission at runtime inside onCreate method of your activity...

```
private final int MY_PERMISSIONS_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS =1;
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Permission is not granted
    } else {
        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS),
                MY_PERMISSIONS_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS)
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
} else {
    // Permission has already been granted
}
```

Comment: REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS is not a dangerous permission according to the docs, you don't ask runtime permission for that. Also it just allows your app to be whitelisted, the permission itself doesn't whitelist your app.

Comment: let me try this

Comment: since I am new to android now I am confused. I don't know where  I have to use this code

Comment: use inside onCreate method of your launcher activity

Comment: @SachinSoma how is that going to fix the problem? The official docs seem pretty clear

Comment: but its showing errors, first error on   3rd line (permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS)  and next error on 7th line (arrayOf) then again in 8th line (permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS) could you please help to find solution

Comment: yes, I tried this but its showing error..so tried another I will post it as answer, and it asking for permission when we opening app.

Comment: see the comment above, my second last comment

Answer (score 0):

Here is the kotlin version of @Shafeeq Mohammed Answer and it worked for me. Thank you

```
         fun checkBatteryOptimization(mContext: Context) {

            val powerManager =
                mContext.getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
            val packageName = mContext.packageName
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                val i = Intent()
                if (!powerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
                    i.action = Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS
                    i.data = Uri.parse("package:$packageName")
                    mContext.startActivity(i)
                }
            }
        }
```